# closing dialog box also closes main window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I created a dialog box & connected it to main window.Dialog purpose is to assign values to variables when buttons are pressed.My problem is that when i try to close dialog box it also closes the main window.This is code from main window file.

```
from dialog import Ui_Dialog as Form
```

This following is the function used to open dialog box

```
def open_dialog(self):
    ap = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ap.setStyle('fusion')
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dialog.ui = Form()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.exec_()
```

I tried to fix it with help of google.I added (accept/reject) buttonbox of pyqt5 but that also close the main window with dialog box

Comment: Why do you create a new QApplication? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create new QApplication object in your code.Your code should be like this

```
def open_dialog(self):
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dialog.ui = Form()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.exec_()
```

remove this from code

```
ap = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```